# CefSharp - Change Loading Screen Background Color

Tags: css, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Is it possible to change the loading screen color on CEFSharp. Like Chrome, when loading a new url it will show a white page until its loaded and rendered. Is it possible to change this loading color to black?

With CEF directly, there seems to be a command line argument: --background-color=black (Source https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1984/momentary-white-flash-with-osr-in#comment-33637201)

But there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with CEFSharp Directly.

Answer (score 4):

Wow, I'm super duper late. But this is how I did it,

```
var sett = new CefSharp.BrowserSettings();
sett.BackgroundColor = ColorToUInt(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 27, 40, 56));
chromium.BrowserSettings = sett;
```

Color to Uint function,

```
public static uint ColorToUInt(Color color)
{
    return (uint)((color.A << 24) | (color.R << 16) | (color.G << 8) | (color.B << 0));
}
```

Comment: In version `67.0.0` you will be able to use `browserSettings.BackgroundColor = Cef.ColorSetARGB(0, 255, 255, 255);`

Comment: apparently Visual Studio isn't recognizing `chromium.BrowserSettings` with intellisense, so I sat here looking through documentation for an hour before simply brute-forcing the code (handwriting it), and then Visual Studio recognized the property anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found this property in CefSharp: `IBrowserSettings.BackgroundColor` ([docs](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_IBrowserSettings_BackgroundColor.htm)).

Comment: How do I actually apply this property?

Answer (score -1):

On button click:

Dim script="document.body.style.backgroundcolor='black';"

Browser.executescriptasync(script)

//that is if u using vb

Answer (score -1):

I was having an issue with CEF showing a white blank page until the page I set it to load actually loaded. This seems to happen when the load function is called and the page is slow to load

```
string url = "https://google.com";    
chromiumWebBrowser.load(url);
```

I found that the browser will retain the current page while loading the next page, so I solved the "white page problem" by loading the page like this:

```
string url = "https://google.com";
int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
string colorString = $"#{r.ToString("X2")}{g.ToString("X2")}{b.ToString("X2")}";
string htmlStr = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style=\"background-color:" + colorString + ";\" > <script> location.href='"+url+"'; </script> </body></html>";
chromiumWebBrowser.LoadHtml(htmlStr);
```

I hope this can be helpfull to soneone